Movie where man is teaching Spanish speakers English and has a heart attack
I am trying to remember a movie where there is a man teaching a Spanish to English class and I'm pretty sure I remember him heaving a heart attack. The scene I remember he is standing in front of the class and says "Uno momento por favor." The class then mirrors back "One moment please" as he stumbles out of the class and passes out.
I'm not positive but I do think it is in the same movie that the man loses his car in one way or another and his class helps him fix or gets him a new one.
I watched this years ago in high school and if I had to take a guess on the year of the movie it would have to be the 90's or 80's most likely though it might be as old as the 70's. 
Sorry this isn't a ton to go off of but that's all I can remember.
